# Record Screencast on Active Area

Tags: screencast

I have seen screencast record that were posted. They were not full screen capture but only a portion of the screen. Hovering the mouse on screencast review the tool tip "Capture a video of the active area or whole Blender window". As implied by the tool tip, there must be a way to record a selected region of the window but I have searched all over the internet and found no answer.

Could anyone enlighten me?